# Need to use pointer-events but clashes with other elements

Tags: html, css, z-index, pointer-events

I'm creating following website:

www.melkerhei.be/smeltkroes/index.html

On the desktop version, everything is fine. But when optimizing the mobile version I faced a problem that I can't solve.

Thinks that should work together (on mobile):

- The top left logo should be clickable
- The artists and other elements should be clickable
- The objects (images) at the edges should be on the foreground

So I tried it with and without the pointer-events attribute.
(added it to a css class that's only used on mobile and on the img itself)
The z-index'es of the edge-images are higher because they need to be on the foreground.

So when I delete the pointer-events:none from the css class, the logo is not clickable.
When I add pointer-events:none; to the mobile css class, the logo is clickable but the other elements are not clickable anymore.

Comment: Why is your header element 100% of the page height? That seems like a poor layout choice...

Comment: @Martin, for the edge images, either way, that doesn't mather for this problem?